# Socket io emit from server to a single user

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io, rabbitmq

Please someone help me with this, I have been trying to initiate a like mechanism that will return a message to the liked user, using socket io and rabbitmq, I get back the emited message from the client, but when I emit to a particular user from the server it doesn't get to the user. When I broadcast to other users, it works fine but to just one user using the room that was created during sign in, using the user's id, it doesn't work: Below are my codes:

**SERVER:**

```
import http from 'http';
import 'dotenv/config';
import app from './app';
import startup from './startup';
import AppLogger from './utils/AppLogger';
import RabbitMqService from './services/RabbitMqService';

const rabbitMqService = new RabbitMqService();

const logger = AppLogger.init('server').logger;
const port = process.env.PORT || 5010;

const server = http.createServer(app);

async function startRabbitMqService() {
  try {
    await rabbitMqService.connectToRabbitMQ();
    rabbitMqService.setupSocketIO(server);
    server.listen(port, () => logger.info(`Server running on port: ${port}`));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error setting up RabbitMQ and Socket.IO:', error);
  }
}

async function startServer() {
   try {
      await startup();
      await startRabbitMqService();
   } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error starting the server:', error);
   }
}

startServer();
```

**RABBITMQ SERVICE:**

```
import amqp, { Connection, Channel, Message } from 'amqplib';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';
import settings from '../config/settings';
import RedisService from './RedisService';
import { corsOptions } from '../app';
import AppLogger from '../utils/AppLogger';
import CustomAPIError from '../exceptions/CustomAPIError';
import HttpStatus from '../helpers/HttpStatus';
import datasources from  './dao';
import UserController from "../controller/UserController";

const userController = new UserController();

const logger = AppLogger.init('server').logger;
const redisService = new RedisService();

class RabbitMqService {
  private connection: Connection | null;
  private channel: Channel | null;
  private io: Server<any, any, any, any> | null;
  private socketMap: Map<any, Socket>;

  constructor() {
    this.connection = null;
    this.channel = null;
    this.io = null;
    this.socketMap = new Map<any, Socket>();
  }

  async connectToRabbitMQ(): Promise<void> {
    this.connection = await amqp.connect(settings.rabbitMq.connection);
    this.channel = await this.connection.createChannel();
    await this.consumeMessagesFromRabbitMQ('chat');
    await this.consumePrivateMessagesFromRabbitMQ();
    await this.consumeLikeDislikeActionsFromRabbitMQ();
  }

  async disconnectFromRabbitMQ(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.channel) {
      await this.channel.close();
      this.channel = null;
    }
    if (this.connection) {
      await this.connection.close();
      this.connection = null;
    }
  }

  async sendMessageToRabbitMQ(queue: string, message: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      if (this.channel) {
        this.channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(message));
      } else {
        throw new CustomAPIError('RabbitMQ channel is not available', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new CustomAPIError('Error while sending message to RabbitMQ', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code);
    }
  }

  async consumeMessagesFromRabbitMQ(queue: string): Promise<void> {
    if (this.channel) {
      this.channel.assertQueue(queue);
      this.channel.consume(queue, (msg: Message | null) => {
        if (msg) {
          // Broadcast the received message to all connected clients via Socket.io
          this.io?.emit('chat message', msg.content.toString());
          this.channel!.ack(msg);
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw new CustomAPIError('RabbitMQ channel is not available', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code);
    }
  }

  async sendMessageToUser(senderId: string, receiverId: string, message: string) {
    const receiverSocket = this.socketMap.get(receiverId);

    if (receiverSocket) {
      receiverSocket.emit('privateMessage', { senderId, message });
    } else {
      // If the receiver is not connected via WebSocket, send the message via RabbitMQ
      const payload = { senderId, receiverId, message };
      await this.sendMessageToRabbitMQ('privateMessages', JSON.stringify(payload));
    }
  }

  async consumePrivateMessagesFromRabbitMQ(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.channel) {
      this.channel.assertQueue('privateMessages');
      this.channel.consume('privateMessages', (msg) => {
        if (msg) {
          const { senderId, receiverId, message } = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
          const receiverSocket = this.socketMap.get(receiverId);

          if (receiverSocket) {
            receiverSocket.emit('privateMessage', { senderId, message });
          }
          this.channel!.ack(msg);
        }
      }, { noAck: false });
    } else {
      throw new CustomAPIError('RabbitMQ channel is not available', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code);
    }
  }
  
  handleLikeDislike(fromUserId: any, toUserId: any, action: any) {
    // Assume 'action' can be 'like' or 'dislike'
    for (const key of this.socketMap.keys()) {
      console.log(key, 'keys');
    }
    const toUserSocket = this.socketMap.get(toUserId);

    if (toUserSocket) {
      for (const [key, socket] of this.socketMap.entries()) {
        if(key === toUserId) {
          console.log(key, socket.id, 'to-confirm');
        }
      }
      // If the 'toUser' is connected via WebSocket
      console.log('shey o wole')
      toUserSocket.emit('likeDislike', { fromUserId, action });
    } else {
      // If the 'toUser' is not connected via WebSocket, send the action via RabbitMQ
      this.sendMessageToRabbitMQ('likeDislikeActions', JSON.stringify({ fromUserId, toUserId, action }));
    }
  }

  async consumeLikeDislikeActionsFromRabbitMQ() {
    if (this.channel) {
      this.channel.assertQueue('likeDislikeActions');
      console.log('Waiting for like...');
      this.channel.consume('likeDislikeActions', (msg) => {
        if (msg) {
          const { fromUserId, toUserId, action } = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
          
          const toUserSocket = this.socketMap.get(toUserId);
          if (toUserSocket) {
            toUserSocket.emit('likeDislike', { fromUserId, action });
          }

          this.channel!.ack(msg);
        }
      }, { noAck: false }); // Set options with noAck: false for manual message acknowledgment
    } else {
      throw new CustomAPIError('RabbitMQ channel is not available', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code);
    }
  }
 
  setupSocketIO(server: any): void {
    this.io = new Server(server, {
      cors: corsOptions
    });

    userController.setIO(this.io);

  this.io.on('connection', (socket: Socket<any, any, any, any>) => {
      console.log(`Client connected. ${socket.id}`);
      logger.info(socket.id);
  
      socket.on('userId', (userId: any) => {
        if (userId) {
          socket.join(userId);
          console.log(`Socket joined room for userId: ${userId}`);
        } else {
            console.log('Invalid or disconnected socket.');
        }
      });

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected.');
        logger.info(`Client with id ${socket.id} disconnected`);
        // Handle socket disconnection and leave rooms if needed
        // Example: socket.leaveAll(); // Leave all rooms this socket was a part of
      });
  
      socket.on('liked', (data: any) => {
        // Extract the target user's ID from the received data
        console.log(`recieved ${data.targetUserId}`)
        const targetUserId = data.targetUserId //data.targetUserId;

        // Check if the targetUserId is available
        if (targetUserId) {
          console.log('sent something FE')
            // Emit the 'likeDislike' event to the room of the target user
            socket.to(targetUserId).emit('likeDislike', data);
        } else {
            console.log('Invalid target user ID provided.');
        }
      });
  
      

      const rooms = this.io?.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(socket.id);
      console.log(`Rooms for socket ${socket.id}:`, rooms);
  });

  }
  
}


export default RabbitMqService;
```

**FRONT END**

```
const handleLogin = async () => {  
  const { data: login } = await axiosClient.post(`${API_ROOT}/sign-in-user`, {
    email: phone,
    password
  });

  const { permissions, userId } = jwt_decode(login.result);
  socket.emit('userId', userId);
  
  sessionStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE.permissions, JSON.stringify(permissions));
  sessionStorage.setItem(settings.auth.admin, login.result);

  navigate("/customer/page")
  reload()
};

const likeUser = () => { 
    const targetUserId = '653bcbbba7a66c9d4d22b179' 
    socket.emit('liked', {targetUserId}) 
}

useEffect(() => { 
    console.log(socket, 'did you come') 
    socket.on('likeDislike', (data) => { 
        console.log(data, 'response') 
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    });

    return () => {
      socket.off('likeDislike');
    }; 
}, [socket.connected]);
```

**THE FRONT END SOCKET CONNECTION:**

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'; import settings from './settings';
const socket = io("http://localhost:5010");

socket.on('connect', () => {
 console.log('Connected to the server');
});

socket.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log('Received message:', message);
});

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('Disconnected from the server');
});

export default socket;
```

Comment: Fixed!. Had to emit the userId and join a room with it every time it disconnects.